# How to change the value of a text box to a be valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am using jQuery for my text boxes, and I am trying to update one of them dynamically, as in the following code:

```
p.updateDeposit = function (formElement, amount) {
  if (this.defaultDeposit + amount < 10) {
    this.defaultDeposit = 10;
  } else {
    this.defaultDeposit = this.defaultDeposit + amount;
  }
  $(formElement + " #depositAmount").val(this.defaultDeposit);
}
```

I have 2 buttons to add and subtract from the deposit, which calls that function:

```
$('#paymentDetailsForm #moreMoney').fastClick(function () {
  that.updateDeposit('#paymentDetailsForm', 25);
});
$('#paymentDetailsForm #lessMoney').fastClick(function () {
  that.updateDeposit('#paymentDetailsForm', -25);
});
```

And I have a function to validate a manual input by the user:

```
p.validateUserDepositInput = function (formElement, input) {
  if (isNaN(input)) {
    $(formElement + " #depositAmount").val(this.defaultDeposit);
  } else {
    this.defaultDeposit = parseFloat(input);
  }
}
```

I am also using jQuery validator for error alerts.

The problem is when the user writes a `NaN` into the text box, and then presses the button to add to the amount, I can see the number changes in the box - but the error `alert` `deposit must be more than 10` is still on! and it stays on until the user enters a number greater than 10.

In other words: the .val operator does not have an effect on the jQuery validator.

Is there another method I can use to update the text box AND call the validation function at the same time?

Thank you!

Comment: you can chose to validate this inside your updateDeposit  function so if isn't ok return a false and stop your code

Comment: you mean i can tell jQuery to validate it for me inside the updateDeposit function? Because i need the jQuery validator, since i am using error-data-theme.

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/, http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ -> so you can validate inside your function; it's enough just to call it

Comment: Thanks alot. it looks promissing, but it seems at the link you attached they show how how to bind a validation to an element. How do i trigger that validation manualy?

Comment: I think i got it. $(formElement + " #depositAmount").validate() ?